# Java code to display the contents of html page

Tags: java, html

Could someone please tell me how to read the contents of the html page which is store in my local system using java program?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Yes, someone can tell you the answer.

```
BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new FileInputStream(new File("c:/my.html")));
String inputLine;

while ((inputLine = is.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(inputLine);
}
is.close()
```